# JSON: handle null value from MySQL export

Tags: mysql, json, data-extraction

I export data from MySQL into a JSON file, but there is an error due to null value. How do I handle this?

SQL query:

```
select industry, ... from table1;
```

where some of the industry gives null value:
[image]

JSON format

```
[{"industry":"entertainment", ...}, {"industry":"", ...}, {"industry":NULL, ...}]
```

The error is due to the 3rd object value in the array (i.e. NULL)
[image]

I tried:

```
select cast(industry as char), ... from table1;
```

Unfortunately, it still gives the same error. Because in the MySQL cell, it shows NULL value.

Thanks!

Update:
As there will be other variables in each object, I would like to change the NULL value in SQL either to "" or "NULL".

I export the data from MySQL using the highlighted button:
[image]

Comment: Do you need `NULL` values? May be `select industry from table1 where industry is not null;`?

Comment: @2kai, hi, I need the NULL value, I hope to change it either to "" or "NULL". Reason being I will have other variables in each object. If I use your query, I might lose some of the required data. I have updated my questions. Thanks!

Comment: How are you generating that invalid JSON? We can't help you fix a process we don't know anything about. A string with the word "NULL" is completely different from an null value, in SQL, JSON and most other languages.

Comment: Works for now and how will you tell if the value was empty string or `NULL` in the original database?

Comment: That last screenshot does not belong to MySQL. MySQL doesn't have buttons or windows, it doesn't have any kind of user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifnull` to cast your `NULL` values

`select ifnull(industry, '') from table1;`

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm :)

Comment: Why should this be necessary?

Comment: It reminds me of a client who had an "EMAIL" column in his database and when his customer didn't have e-mail address he typed "none" :)

Comment: I suppose MySQL export to JSON is not perfect.

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL export to JSON does not even exist. You have to code your own or use someone else's code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), the correct value is `null` (lowercase):

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans,
>   and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).

... and:

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
>   the following three literal names:
>
> ```
> false null true
> ```

If you're getting uppercase `NULL` you're either composing JSON manually or your JSON library has a serious bug.

Comment: Hi, I did not compose JSON manually, the value NULL comes from MySQL cell. I have added a new screenshot.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a MySQL column of [type JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)?

Comment: No, I export the data from MySQL into a JSON file. But in some of the cells, they give a "null" value shown in the screenshot. Hence after export, it gives [{...},{...},{"industry":NULL}]

Comment: Then the error is clearly in the tool/code/script/process you use to export data from MySQL into a JSON file. But I have the impression that you don't really want to fix that, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right that the process that I used to export data is the issue. I have attached an image to show how I export the data. Not sure how I can fix that when I simply click the button and don't write any code.

Comment: You probably click an icon to start that program. Does it have a text with the name of the software? How about the window title, does it display the name of the program? Or perhaps you can ask whoever installed the program in your computer.